# Pandas subtract column values only when non nan

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe `df` as follows with about 200 columns:

```
Date        Run_1   Run_295 Prc
2/1/2020                    3
2/2/2020    2               6
2/3/2020            5       2
```

I want to subtract column `Prc` from columns `Run_1 Run_295 Run_300` only when they are non-Nan or non empty, to get the following:

```
Date        Run_1   Run_295 
2/1/2020                            
2/2/2020    -4                      
2/3/2020            3
```

I am not sure how to proceed with the above.

Code to reproduce the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = """Date,Run_1,Run_295,Prc
2/1/2020,,,3
2/2/2020,2,,6
2/3/2020,,5,2"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
print(df)
```

Comment: are you always looking to subtract the last column and is always the date column the first barring which you want to perform this?

Comment: no I have column names so Prc is the name which needs to be subtracted

Comment: can you try: `m = df.set_index('Date')` and then `final = m.drop('Prc',1).sub(m['Prc'],axis=0).reset_index()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply subtract it. It exactly does what you want:

```
df.Run_1-df.Prc
```

Here is the complete code to your output:

```
df.Run_1= df.Run_1-df.Prc
df.Run_295= df.Run_295-df.Prc
df.drop('Prc', axis=1, inplace=True)

df

    Date        Run_1   Run_295
0   2/1/2020    NaN     NaN
1   2/2/2020    -4.0    NaN
2   2/3/2020    NaN     3.0
```

Comment: I have 100 columns. I cant do this

Comment: However you can do this in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps, `melt` to unpivot your dataframe

Then  `loc` to handle assignment

& `GroupBy` to reomake your original df.

sure there is a better way to this, but this avoids loops and `apply`

```
cols = df.columns

s = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Date','Prc'],value_name='Run Rate')

s.loc[s['Run Rate'].isnull()==False,'Run Rate'] = s['Run Rate'] - s['Prc']

df_new = s.groupby([s["Date"], s["Prc"], s["variable"]])["Run Rate"].first().unstack(-1)
```

---

```
print(df_new[cols])

variable      Date  Run_1  Run_295  Prc
0         2/1/2020    NaN      NaN    3
1         2/2/2020   -4.0      NaN    6
2         2/3/2020    NaN      3.0    2
```